# How to calculate ETA without a map

Tags: sql, json, vb6

Need a little help from someone who knows a little about logistics;

---

I am currently working with an application known as Framework. The application is not really something that I am familiar with, but regardless I can figure out how it works. One of the tabs running in the application is for expected orders (shipping trucks). Within that, I am able to see where an outbound truck's current location is, as well as it's destination. I am trying to add functionality to the application that would allow me to see an estimated time of arrival to its current destination + the drive back to my location. This seems simple enough, but I'm trying to figure out the best way that I could calculate this. I looked into The Google Distance Matrix API, but I have no need to display a map on the application, all I want is the ETA. I am pretty inexperienced with this kind of thing, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks guys.

This may not be the best forum for this question...

Comment: Well the problem with Google Distance Matrix is that if you're using it, you have to display a Google map. If you try to use just the database information, it will deny you. I haven't heard of OSRM but I will check into that, thanks!

Comment: I've posted as a full answer now. You may also want to check out the [GIS stackexchange site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google Distance Matrix requires you to display the map. An alternative is the open source [OSRM project](http://project-osrm.org/). Natively it's a C++ engine for routing, which outputs directions and the total route information so the any map display is up to you.

There is a demo and HTTP API hosted on the project site but you will need to check if it's suitable for your usage level.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but depending on the size of your delivery area, and how accurate you want the estimated time, you may be able to keep it all in a database.

Let's assume your delivery area is 10 miles x 10 miles.

- So that's 100 square miles. We'll use each square mile as a point.
- Do a one time calculation of how long it will take to get from each
  point to the rest. You can
- use the Google Distance Matrix API for this since you're only doing
  this once.
- This will give you 10,000 records that has every point to point time.

So, if your truck is in point 25, and has to get to point 64, you do a lookup and see that it should take about 10 minutes. plus the drive from point 64 back to the warehouse (point 10) is 8 minutes. Then you'll know the truck should be back in about 18 minutes.

It's not super accurate, but it might be close enough for your needs. I would be curious if you do implement this method.

Btw, if your delivery area is 100 miles x 100 miles, then that would be 100,000,000 location points if each point is 1 square mile. If that's too much, then if you increase your point size to 2 miles x 2 miles (4 square miles), then that's about 6,000,000 records.